# Ubuntu 20.04 come back to the login page after I login

Tags: 20.04, login

When I start Ubuntu 20.04 and I login, It shows the console with a hyphen, and come backs to the login page. I already looked in some forums and pages but nothing worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: I'd suggest switching to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) & check you have sufficient space in $HOME (*your user directory*) as that's the most common cause I encounter.  If you made changes last session that's another cause (eg. to graphics drivers, python3 defaults etc) but you should already know what you did last session & have mentioned that.